# How many btrfs snapshots is too many?

Tags: btrfs, snapshot

I've been doing daily snapshots on a btrfs subvolume for nearly 3 years, resulting in over a thousand snapshots. I am experiencing occasional small stalls (a few seconds) in basic filesystem operations such as creating new folders and moving files. There is plenty of free and unallocated space left. `filefrag` does not report excessive fragmentation on a random sample of files I've tested.

I've not been able to find any published gotchas on snapshots being the root cause of this issue, but is there any issue with making and keeping a large number of them?